# handling echo statements in php and android

Tags: php, android

Suppose there's a scenario where in PHP, I am echoing like :

echo ' some html response tags ';

then when I connect my android with retrofit then should I make a separate for the same query for android ? I am literally confused. should I use JSON encode or a total different echo statement (for android).

I hope you understand my question. My question is how to have different echo in the same query for web and android. Please help me understand this.

Comment: It depends on your Android code. Is it expecting a `json` response from `PHP` and you can't modify this behaviour? If so, you should pass an additional parameter to your `PHP` API and switch the type of return: `echo` for web and `json_encode` for Android.

Comment: Show some Android code on how you cal PHP and use the data, otherwise this is only theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` is data interchange so this is the main job for `JSON`, using echo is not a good way to interchange any data there are a lot of scenarios that echo could have a bad impact on your data and interchange process.